# Why does print random just gives an error

Tags: python, random

```
from random import *

items =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print(random.choice(items))
```

Normally that works completely fine but i get that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Coding\Python\Projects\item_generator", line 6, in <module>       
    print(random.choice(items))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildcard imports like in `from random import *` are not recommended as making difficult to track what is going on (not just from `random`, from any package actually). But if you decide to use it then use `choice` (or whatever other function defined in it) directly (without the `random.` in front). Otherwise use `import random` and then use `random.choice`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import random
```

instead of this

```
from random import *
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply fix the import. This should work:

```py
import random

items =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print(random.choice(items))
```